# Incrementing and decrementing a file pointer

Tags: c

For a file pointer, what would be the equivalent of the `++` and `--` that can be done on normal pointers (for example, strings). As an example:

```
fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
fptr--;
```

Why can't something like the above be done? What would be the way to do this instead?

Comment: Because a file pointer is **not** a pointer to the content of the file in memory. It's a pointer to a complex structure (that is, `FILE`) used by libc to identify an open file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fseek()` function with the `SEEK_CUR` flag.

```
fseek(fptr, -1, SEEK_CUR);
```

`SEEK_CUR` means that the file position should be set relative to the current position in the file. A positive offset means to add to the position, a negative offset means to subtract from the position.

Answer (score 2):

A "file pointer" (or `FILE *`) is *not* a "pointer to a file".  It's really a file *descriptor*, or a "file handle".  It's a data structure you use to read and write to/from files.

You get a file handle when you open a file by calling `fopen`, and you use a file handle when you perform explicit read, write, and other operations by calling functions like `fread`, `fprintf`, and `fseek`, and you dispose of a file handle when you're done with it by calling `fclose`.  But you never do any pointer operations on it: you never put `*` in front of it to fetch its contents, and you never do pointer arithmetic on it, with `++` or any other operators.

It is, arguably, a blemish in C's type system that we can tell that this type is a pointer at all.  If it were an opaque type, questions like this wouldn't come up.

The only time you could conceivably write

```
fp++
```

would be if you had an array of `FILE` structs you were iterating over:

```
 FILE files[10];              /* the 10 files I'm writing to */

 /* now write 'x' to all the files */
 FILE *fdp = files;
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    putc('x', fp++);          /* wrong, wrong, wrong */
```

But this won't work at all, for several reasons.  For one thing, you could never have an array of `FILE` structures like that.  (Well, you could try, but it would be pointless and nonportable.)  And, for another thing, you'd run up against a subtle limitation of `putc()`, which is that it's allowed to be implemented as a macro, and it's not safe to give it a file pointer argument with side effects.  (This is, admittedly, a terribly obscure point, although I guess it's why programmers these days seem to be taught to call `fputc` instead.)

Bottom line, don't try to use `++` or `--` on file pointers.